# Check if Session still exists

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-10

On the time of login, coldfusion server assigns me a `CFID` and a `CFTOKEN`. Later on using those `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` how can I check if my session still exists or not.

In other words I want a function that will take `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` and will tell if the session related to those `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` still exists or not.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please specify the higher goal you want to achieve? that may give you much more answers.

Comment: From a mobile App I want to send a call to the server to check if my session still exists or not. If not, I'll send the user to the login screen.

Comment: simply when user logs in set a custom session variable `Session.HasUserLogedIn` to `true`. Eachtime a request comes in from mobile app to server, you need to check if that variable has the value of the `true` if yes server the user if NOT then her session is expired; redirect her to login screen. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: and @chris-blackwell did write a functional example for you there :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to set a flag in the session when your user logs in.

for example

```
<cfset session.loggedin = true />
```

then when you want to check if the user still has a valid session you can do

```
<cfparam name="session.loggedin" default="false" />
<cfif NOT session.loggedin>
  <!--- do something here --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way. But I was expecting there would be a proper way as well. For example a coldfusion function etc.

Comment: I'll accept your answer unless someone posts a proper way. Thanks

Comment: That is the proper way, really. You can do `StructKeyExists(session,'anyvaluethatshouldexist')`, but that's the same as what Chris has done above

Comment: I'd go with the strucktkeyexists option myself.

Comment: What Chris has suggested is the proper way to check it. both `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` are stored in client side as cookies. you can not authenticate users just by relying to them. you should check it somehow via server side.

Comment: there is no built in function to do what you are asking, although it is possible to access session information through undocumented apis.  The way I have suggested would be the recommended method.

Comment: What does "Session rotated successfully" mean?  I keep seeing that in the cfide/administrator.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with Chris' answer and is usually the standard norm when checking for sessions.

These two cookies are meant to "link" your browser with your session, not to actually maintain that session (in fact, I believe these cookies are set to expire in 30 years(?) and are even ignored if you're using `J2EE session management` if I'm not mistaken). From the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html):

> To use client and session variables, ColdFusion must be able to
> identify the client. It normally does so by setting the following two
> cookie values on the client’s system:
>
> **CFID:** A sequential client identifier
>
> **CFToken:** A random-number client security token These cookies uniquely identify the client to
> ColdFusion, which also maintains copies of the variables as part of
> the Session and Client scopes.

As you can read [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1537-The-Same-CFID-CFTOKEN-Values-Are-Used-Across-ColdFusion-Session-Timeouts.htm), Ben Nadel did some playing around with `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` where CF used the same `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` cookies to create NEW sessions after it had expired.

As for your 'ColdFusion Proper' way, you *could* look into using [CFLOGIN](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflogin.html) and [other security tags](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/securing-applications.html) which are meant to assist in handling authentication but I don't believe many people use it because maintaining your session is very easy as Chris demonstrated.